FPS camera not rotating when the game is built in Unity
I have a 3D scene in unity with an fps camera. The camera is on a different object which follows the player with a script. The problem is that the camera is not turning and is locked into a rotation when the game is built. The weird thing is that I use raycasts from the camera's forward, and these raycast actually hit different things, so it seems like the camera is rotating but the image is not moving at all. Could someone please help me with this? I am completely lost.
First I thought the probelm is that there are 2 cameras in the scene (the other one is for rendering 3D moving ui), but after deleting the other camera the main one still doesn't work when the game is built.

Can you please provide more details with some screenshots showing the issue. Also can you provide your source code regarding your camera movement or player movement
